# Laravel PHP Excel Export memory exausted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpexcel

So i am having this error on exporting my data on excel.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home1/greatsup/public_html/system/application/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 889
```

Which is surprising because the table that i have been exporting ONLY contains 10 rows. So i tried printing it first to see if any data is fetch but still got the same error.

PS: i tried using the excel export on larger sets of data. But in this controller i am having a hard time figuring what is the problem.

Here is my code

```
 public function excel_export(Request $request) {

    $post = $request->all();
    $dateFrom = $post['updated_at_from'];
    $dateTo = $post['updated_at_to'];

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
        die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("templates/unit_specifications_format.xlsx");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator(Config::$APPNAME)
                                 ->setLastModifiedBy(Config::$APPNAME)
                                 ->setTitle(null)
                                 ->setSubject(null)
                                 ->setDescription(null)
                                 ->setKeywords(null)
                                 ->setCategory(null);
    $fontSettings = array(
    'font'  => array(
        'bold'  => true,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FFFFFF'),
        'size'  => 12,
        'name'  => 'calibri'
    ));
    $headerSettings = array('fill' => array(
    'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
    'color' => array('rgb' => \App\Resources\Config::$PRIMARYCOLOR)
    ));
    $borderSettings = $BStyle = array(
      'borders' => array(
        'allborders' => array(
          'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
        )
      )
    );

    $query = DB::table('unit_specifications')->get();
    print_r($query);
    exit;


    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $start = 5;
    $row = $start;
    $column = 0;
    $no = 1;




    $allCombination = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(0).$start.':'.PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($column-1).($row-1);
    $sheet->getStyle($allCombination)->applyFromArray($borderSettings);
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$this->excel_filename.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate');
    header ('Pragma: public');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
}
```

Any thoughts what i have missed ?

Comment: Rather than writing so much code to download a file, you may want to use the [Laravel download response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#file-downloads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you aren't sure what your PHP memory limit is set to, it's helpfully included in the error message. The size is reported in bytes, though, so we've done some conversions for you:**

```
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 8388608 Bytes Exhausted - 8 MB
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 16777216 Bytes Exhausted - 16 MB
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 33554432 Bytes Exhausted - 32 MB
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 67108864 Bytes Exhausted - 64 MB
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted - 128 MB
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 268435456 Bytes Exhausted - 256 MB
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 536870912 Bytes Exhausted - 512 MB
PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 1073741824 Bytes Exhausted - 1 GB
```

to solve this error go to your php.ini

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); // or you could use 1G
```

it depends on what Apache you use most of them use word

> memory_limit

so search about this word and modify it and check your data 
hope this solve your problem